# How to determine and send alert SMS for next bus stop in a GPS tracking system?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, gps, tracking

In my gps tracking system (PHP/MySql) I have got 5 Stops for a vehicle.

Whenever the bus reaches stop 1, the passengers at stop 2 should get an SMS alert. And in the same way for the sops followed by.

I have given stops as points. How can I determine whether the bus reached a particular stop? Should always monitor all 6 stop whether the bus reached once the trip is started?
Can anybody give some idea?

(Map used: Google Map/Openlayers)

See the image.

[image: Image showing 6 Bus Stops and start & stop points]

Comment: This will have to be done by some server code. The Google Maps API/Openlayers code will run in Javascript on the client browser, and cannot send sms or other such alerts.

Comment: Geofencing will be able to trigger an 'event' - using your red (buffer) circles as polygon. see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/geofences#overview

Comment: Should check entry/exit for all 6 stops all the time since the start of the trip towards the end? Please share some logic.

Comment: Is there any logical error in the question?